# Finding a Bounded Measurable Set and Sequence of Simple Functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $f$ be a measurable function on $E$ that is finite a.e. on $E$ and $m(E) < \infty$. Show that for each $\epsilon > 0$, show that there is a measurable set $F$ contained in $E$ and a sequence $\{\varphi_n \}$ of simple functions on $E$ such that $f$ is bounded on $F$ and $m(E-F) < \epsilon$.

I recently solved the following two problems:

(1) Let $f$ be a bounded measurable function on $E$. Show that there are sequences of simple functions on $E$, $\{\varphi_n\}$ and $\{\psi_n\}$, such that $\{\varphi_n\}$ is increasing and $\{\psi_n \}$ is decreasing and each of these sequences converges to $f$ uniformly on $E$.

(2) Let $f$ be a measurable function on $E$ that is finite a.e. on $E$ and $m(E) < \infty$. For each $\epsilon > 0$, show that there is a measurable set $F$ contained in $E$ such that $f$ is bounded on $F$ and $m(E-F) < \epsilon$ (see this [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2480534/almost-finite-measurable-function-is-almost-bounded)).

My question is, to solve the problem I am currently working on wouldn't I just use (2) to get $F$ over which $f$ is bounded,and then apply (1) to $f$ over the bounded measurable set $F$? In fact, according to (1), we can get two sequences of simple functions each of which uniformly converge to $f$ on $F$. The only thing left to do would be extending $\varphi_n$ to all of $E$ by defining it to be constant over $E-F$? Is it really that easy?

Comment: In your question it is not clear what conditions the $\phi_n$ must satisfy.

Comment: @drhab I guess the only condition on $\varphi_n$ is that it be a simple function. I typed up the problem exactly as it appears in the book.

Comment: No responses? Bump!

Comment: Yes, it really is that easy (once you have parts (1) and (2), which however aren't too difficult either).